# Combining async operations into one synchronous operation

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a requirement where I need to call multiple APIs asynchronously and combine the result of all the APIs and return it. The issue here is, I need to use this complete method as synchronous wherever I will be using it.
Note: I can't use any of the libraries/frameworks.

```
function op1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({
                firstName: "Nikhil"
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
}

function op2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({
                lastName: "Goyal"
            });
        }, 500);
    });
}

function getName() {
    // Some implementation here
}

const name = getName();
console.log(name.firstName);
console.log(name.lastName);
```

Comment: There's [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: Promise.all() will also return a promise at the end which will be asynchronous. I want something which can resolve in a synchronous manner. If I use Promise.all(), then I need to use getName().then(callback). I need to use it similar to what I have demonstrated.

Comment: `getName()` won't be able to return your object for you, it will either need to return a promise or call some sort of callback with your combined values (you can't "break" out of "asynchronous mode")

Comment: @NikhilGoyal Yes. And you would `await` like you would with a function declared `async`. For example, `const results = await Promise.all([op1(), op2()]);`, then do whatever you need to do with the values in `results`.

Comment: "*I need to use this complete method as synchronous*" - this is plain impossible. Fix the code that uses this method to deal with the asynchrony, there's no way around that.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `async` and `await`.

```
function op1() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({
                firstName: "Nikhil"
            });
        }, 1000);
    });
}

function op2() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve({
                lastName: "Goyal"
            });
        }, 500);
    });
}

async function getName() {
    const a = await op1();
    const b = await op2();
return {firstName: a.firstName, lastName: b.lastName}

}

getName().then(name=> {
console.log(name.firstName);
console.log(name.lastName);
}
);
```